# How to limit google maps api lag when panning the map with lots of markers and polylines?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My question:
**How to make google maps move smother when there is a lot of markers and polylines shown on the map?**

I am asking advices on an application I developed.

The issue happens only in Firefox when the map is moved up,down,left or right with the mouse.

The application shows **about 1000 segments of polylines**, and **around 700 markers** on the map.

All the data is **located inside 7 KML files**.

All the polylines are segments of direction from A to B so they have lots of points.
So I think most of the problem is caused by the size and the number of the polylines.

Similar thread :
- [Need guidance on a Google Map application that has to show 250 000 polylines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888539/need-guidance-on-a-google-map-application-that-has-to-show-250-000-polylines)
- [google maps api v3 no smooth dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645766/google-maps-api-v3-no-smooth-dragging?lq=1)
- [Mapping 400MB KML data in Google Maps - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390057/mapping-400mb-kml-data-in-google-maps-how)

Thank you.

An issue has been opened for a similar problem by someone else, so I don't think I am alone in this situation.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5665

Comment: May i know why a downvote please? Unclear, or unuseful?

Comment: You can use a marker cluster but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: I can't see the relation to KML in your question.

Comment: When I move the map with the mouse it's not smooth at all. And I want it to move smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a solution that improved the movement but it does not resolve completely the issue.
[google maps api v3 no smooth dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645766/google-maps-api-v3-no-smooth-dragging)
http://jsfiddle.net/CX4gN/3/

```
var last = {time : new Date(),    // last time we let an event pass.
            x    : -100,          // last x position af the event that passed.
            y    : -100};         // last y position af the event that passed.
var period = 100; // ms - don't let pass more than one event every 100ms.
var space  = 40;   // px - let event pass if distance between the last and
                  //      current position is greater than 2 px.

function init_map() {
    map_div = document.getElementById("map")
    // map
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.836454, 23.372497),
        zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), map_options);

    // register event handler that will throttle the events.
    // "true" means we capture the event and so we get the event
    // before Google Maps gets it. So if we cancel the event,
    // Google Maps will never receive it.
    map_div.addEventListener("mousemove", throttle_events, true);
};

function throttle_events(event) {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.clientX - last.x, 2) + Math.pow(event.clientY - last.y, 2));
    var time = now.getTime() - last.time.getTime();
    if (distance * time < space * period) {    //event arrived too soon or mouse moved too little or both
        console.log("event stopped");
        if (event.stopPropagation) { // W3C/addEventListener()
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else { // Older IE.
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        };
    } else {
        console.log("event allowed: " + now.getTime());
        last.time = now;
        last.x    = event.clientX;
        last.y    = event.clientY;
    };
};
```

This code is functional but as I said earlier, it doesn't resolve completely the problem.

Other solutions will be welcomed.

[EDIT 2014-03-14]
It is finally the best solution I found and I tested it in production, and it is finally working pretty well.

Comment: it didnt help at all, acutally made it worse